# FORTH why does a negative LSHIFT behave this way?

Tags: bit-shift, forth, gforth

For amusement, I did

```
1 1 RSHIFT . 0  ok
```

I can see here that the native type is twos compliment with that which makes sense because (true is `-1`). However this took me by surprise.

```
1 -1 LSHIFT . -9223372036854775808  ok
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

At the first, the arguments of `lshift` are interpreted as unsigned (so, the number of bits to shifting is always non-negative). At the second,
the reason of the mentioned surprise is an *ambiguous condition*.

An excerpt from the section [6.1.1805 `lshift`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/LSHIFT) of the Forth-2012 Standard:

> An ambiguous condition exists if `u` is greater than or equal to the
> number of bits in a cell.

So, the result in this case depends on particular Forth-system implementation. You should not rely on it.

Note that `u` in the [stack notation](https://forth-standard.org/standard/notation#subsection.2.2.2) means **unsigned** number (single-cell), see the [table 3.1: Data types](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#table:datatypes).

BTW, it is useful in such experiments to use binary number-conversion radix and print numbers as unsigned via [`u.r`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/UDotR)

```
#2 base !
1  #63 lshift #65 u.r
1 -#64 lshift #65 u.r
1 -#65 lshift #65 u.r
1 -#1  lshift #65 u.r
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems

- `LSHIFT` wraps around the bits in the negative direction on a 64 bit 2's compliment representation, **this is what you're seeing**

  ```
  1 -1  LSHIFT . -9223372036854775808  ok
  1 -65 LSHIFT . -9223372036854775808  ok
  1 -64 LSHIFT . 1  ok
  ```
- `LSHIFT` wraps around the bits in the positive direction

  ```
  1 64 LSHIFT . 1  ok
  ```
- `RSHIFT` drops the bits in the positive direction rather than wrapping around

  ```
  1 1 RSHIFT . 0  ok
  ```
- `RSHIFT` drops the bits in the negative direction rather than wrapping around

  ```
  1 -30 RSHIFT . 0  ok
  ```